# Java ResultSet working with postgresql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, resultset

I have a table on my database where it holds 2 columns: uid1 - someone's id, uid2 - his friend.

I want to create a list where I someone's friend - till 5 depth connection.

So I built the following recursive method:

```
    private void recursive(int theUid,ResultSet rs,ArrayList<Integer> friends,int count,int next,PreparedStatement pstmt) throws SQLException{
        if(count>=1 && next==theUid){
            return;
        }
        else if(count>=DEPTH_OF_CONNECTION){
            return;
        }

        else{
            pstmt.setInt(1,next);
            rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
            count++;
            while(rs.next()) {
                friends.add(rs.getInt(1));
                recursive(theUid,rs,friends,count,rs.getInt(1),pstmt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I got the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This
>   ResultSet is closed.  at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2654)     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.next(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1786)

Can you help me find what is the problem?

Comment: You know you can do that with just a single statement in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Talking to the server for every single step is very expensive. A single query with a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) would be the way to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) for jdbc Statement says

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time.

So my guess is you are trying to open too many resultsets for the same PreparedStatement at the same time.

edit:

[Postgres jdbc driver doc](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/statement.html) seems to confirm it:

> You can use a single Statement instance as many times as you want. You could create one as soon as you open the connection and use it for the connection's lifetime. But you have to remember that only one ResultSet can exist per Statement or PreparedStatement at a given time.

Comment: just to complete your [right] answer. The code should take all friends from the resultset, close it and then recurse over the list it got.

Comment: ...or use [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-with.html) :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you are using the ResultSet object to store your statement results and then passing it as a parameter to the recursive function call. So basically you are overwriting the variable and losing the reference to it.  You should either write your sql statement to retrieve the data you need or not pass the same ResultSet object to the recursive call.